# vscode debug showing incorrect variable values?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I upgraded to vscode version 1.75.1 (user setup) yesterday. Today, while debugging, I noticed something very strange. The variable I am watching in the debug window seems to display the wrong values sporadically. I can step through simple console.log statements and watch the variable change values. See the sequence of images. You will a large object in the watch window and logged to the console screen. The next image is one tick away, and while the correct value appears in the console again, the watch value is a completely different value. In the third image the correct value is displayed in both locations.  This is not an issue of concurrent execution. Is anybody else seeing this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
Version: 1.75.1 (user setup)
Commit: 441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf
Date: 2023-02-08T21:32:34.589Z
Electron: 19.1.9
Chromium: 102.0.5005.194
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
Sandboxed: No
```

Rebooted and still have the same issue.  Will try reverting vscode next.

Here is another example.  No way to get into the if(cost.error) statement at the bottom if the value in the watch window (cost.error == undefined) was correct.

[image]

Switching back to version 1.74.3 does NOT have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug that has now been identified: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/1561